# Limit dropzones in Angular CDK drag&drop

Tags: angular, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I haven't used [Angular CDK drag&drop](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api) before and it seems to do what I need in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8y5qe3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-custom-placeholder-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-custom-placeholder-example.ts)

```
<div
  [cdkDropListEnterPredicate]="canDrop(basket)"
  [cdkDropListData]="basket"
  cdkDropList
  class="example-list"
  (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
>
  <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let movie of movies" cdkDrag>
    <div class="example-custom-placeholder" *cdkDragPlaceholder></div>
    {{movie}}
  </div>
</div>
```

However, in that Stackblitz you can drop any list item anywhere in the list. This is however not the behaviour I'm looking for. I would like to give each item DROP restrictions. Meaning that an list item has certain places in the list where it cannot be dropped. In those situations where an item cannot be droppped in a specific dropzone, I would like to show a message inside that zone stating that it is not allowed to drop the item, but (if possible) it might be even better to not show the dropzone at all.

I tried to use **cdkDropListEnterPredicate** but (as you can see in the stackblitz) if I return false from that *canDrop* function, nothing really happens. But maybe I'm doing it all wrong. Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong or what I should be doing?

Comment: I might be missing something, isnt this what you are looking for: https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview

section "Controlling whether an item can be sorted into a particular index"

Comment: As mentioned in comment above, the issue with predict on enter is the item has already “entered” the drop zone. So what you want to do is evaluate if item can be moved inside the drop zone.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I completely missed the examples :( So, if I would like the behaviour I described in my post within a single list, I think I need to use `cdkDropListEnterPredicate`. But I don't understand it. Checkout [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-elvxrc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-enter-predicate-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-enter-predicate-example.html) The function connected to it just returns `false`, but the items are draggable/droppable. How does this work? If I changed the return value to `true` it behaves identical?

Comment: @Jeanluca Scaljeri You're missing something. The `[cdkDropListEnterPredicate]` of the **first list** returns `false` all the time. The **second list** has a different `[cdkDropListEnterPredicate]` (`evenPredicate`). The first predicate returning `false`, causes items not to be able to be dragged back into the top list

Comment: Ah now I see, thnx! So, I can conclude that there is no way to conditionally show a dropzone, right? On the other hand, with **cdkDropListDropped** I can do some validation too, which will probably do the job as well!